# Formula for getting Modified Date equal to Created Date instead of latest Modified Date

Tags: date-time, modified

I'm creating a Time Out column wherein it stores the Modified Date/Time of a list. 
However, I just want to get only the latest Modified Date/Time that is the same Date as the Created Date.

E.g.

```
Created Date/Time = 11/12/2015 10:43 AM

1st Modified Date/Time = 11/12/2015 12:51 PM

2nd Modified Date/Time = 11/12/2015 5:05 PM <---This is the Date/Time I need to keep.

3rd Modified Date/Time = 11/13/2015 8:20 AM
```

I'm stuck in just getting the Modified Date/Time:

```
=IF(Modified=Created,Modified, " ")
```

I'm fairly new to Sharepoint admin, is there any additional functions I can use to improve the above formula without using powershell?

Comment: Calculated column value is evaluated every time item is modified based on item field values. For this scenario it requires access to previous versions of item in calculation which doesn't look feasible. I guess you will have to try custom field / event receivers / workflows.

Answer (score 1):

ListItems have no clue about its History so a Calculated Column Formulas only calculate with the last Created and Modified values.

You have to put your logic in a SharePoint Designer (free tool) **Workflow**:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-workflow-f6a92a4b-c919-40d7-9728-2e79c524764c

- Add a column TimeOutDate

Your workflow should do (something like):

- On item change
- check if todays date is the created date
- if Yes, write modified to TimeOutDate
- if No, do nothing